# The meaning of "bestatued"

Tags: meaning, dictionaries

From "The Magus" by John Fowles:

"Beyond that rose the Regency façade, **bestatued**, many and elegantly windowed, of Cumberland Terrace."

What does "bestatued" mean here?

Comment: Decorated with statues.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from the comment by @ user121863:

There are many English words of this form, bedecked, bedazzled, bewitched, bestrewn,etc.

I'm not certain what meaning is added but the history of the prefix "be-" goes back a long way. All the way to Old English. I think that the author has simply invented a new word, "to bestatue", by using this old way of creating verbs.

> be- word-forming element of verbs and nouns from verbs, with a wide
> range of meaning: "about, around; thoroughly, completely; to make,
> cause, seem; to provide with; at, on, to, for;" from Old English be-
> "about, around, on all sides"  https://www.etymonline.com/word/be-